# how to display weather-icons

Tags: html, css

I'm currently trying to integrate the [weather icons](https://github.com/erikflowers/weather-icons). But if I embed everything and insert it into my HTML, then no icon is displayed. The following is my folder structure and the index.html.

My folder structure looks like:

- css

  - weather-icons-wind.min.css
- font

  - weathericons-regular-webfont.eot
  - weathericons-regular-webfont.svg
  - weathericons-regular-webfont.ttf
  - weathericons-regular-webfont.woff
  - weathericons-regular-webfont.woff2
- index.html

index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <title>weather</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/weather-icons-wind.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>testgt</h1>
    <i class="wi wi-day-sunny"></i>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include the `weather-icons.css` file and not `weather-icons-wind.css`

See here, it works fine.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <title>weather</title>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/weather-icons/2.0.9/css/weather-icons.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>testgt</h1>
    <i class="wi wi-day-sunny"></i>
</body>
```